# In Harry Potter, can a boggart really hurt you?

Tags: harry-potter

When it appeared as a snake to Parvati, would it really be able to bite or choke her, or is it just scaring without actually being able to attack?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

## Unclear - but it can't do as much damage as the real thing.

Lupin decided to use a Boggart for Harry to practice the Patronus Charm on after rejecting the idea of practicing with a real Dementor, because bringing a real Dementor into Hogwarts would be too dangerous.

> “Ah yes,’ said Lupin, when Harry reminded him of his promise at the end of class. ‘Let me see … how about eight o’clock on Thursday evening? The History of Magic classroom should be large enough … I’ll have to think carefully about how we’re going to do this … we can’t bring a real Dementor into the castle to practise on …”
> <sub><sup>- Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban, Chapter 12 (The Patronus)</sup></sub>

In addition, Lupin described a Boggart turned into a Dementor as "the nearest we'll get to a real Dementor", which means that there is a difference between a Boggart in the form of a Dementor and an actual Dementor.

> “What’s that?’ said Harry.
>
> ‘Another Boggart,’ said Lupin, stripping off his cloak. ‘I’ve been combing the castle ever since Tuesday, and very luckily, I found this one lurking inside Mr Filch’s filing cabinet. It’s the nearest we’ll get to a real Dementor. The Boggart will turn into a Dementor when he sees you, so we’ll be able to practise on him. I can store him in my office when we’re not using him; there’s a cupboard under my desk he’ll like.”
> <sub><sup>- Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban, Chapter 12 (The Patronus)</sup></sub>

So - the Boggart can have some of the effects of the creature it transforms into, but likely has a weakened version of their power instead of their full abilities.

Also, when the Boggart turned into a full moon, it didn't cause Lupin to transform into a werewolf.

> “The legless spider had vanished. For a second, everyone looked wildly around to see where it was. Then they saw a silvery white orb hanging in the air in front of Lupin, who said ‘Riddikulus!’ almost lazily.”
> <sub><sup>- Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban, Chapter 7 (The Boggart in the Wardrobe)</sup></sub>

Comment: I'm not sure the second example proves much - after all, it could be possible to turn into *a* dementor, but there's only *one* moon.

Comment: I don't necessarily thinking that Lupin deciding to use a boggart instead of a dementor necessarily means that a boggart then has much weaker powers. It could simply be that a boggart will only be in the form of a dementor when focused on Harry, and so is much easier to control than a permanent dementor

Answer (score 17):

Yes, It can hurt you. When Harry is practicing his Patronus on them, he feels all the effects of a dementor. That’s why Lupin is giving him a chocolate like he did with Harry’s first encounter to a real dementor. He also asks Harry whether he heard James.

Comment: I'm not sure if this generalises. A Dementor is about the most “psychosomatic” kind of foe you can encounter (“...said Lupin thoughtfully ... ‘That suggests that what you fear most of all is – fear. Very wise, Harry.’ ”). I certainly wouldn't take this as evidence that a Snake-Boggart would be able to physically bite or choke its victim. And a Dementor-Boggart probably wouldn't be able to perform the Kiss, either (I seem to vaguely recall this was actually discussed somewhere).

Comment: Maybe boggart is not able to hurt you by touching you as it is merely a illusion but It hurts you anyway because hurting is not all pyhsical.

Comment: @atayenel In that case, the boggart isn't hurting you, you're hurting yourself.

Comment: @isanae this is exactly what *fear* does. With or without a boggart. But if we continue this, this becomes a topic for interpersonal skills...

Comment: Fear can indeed hurt you in real life - there have been documented cases of people being scared to death.  So, depending on physical health of the person, yes a boggart can hurt/kill you.

Comment: @ivanivan So can a spoon if you're scared of spoons, but nobody would say spoons can hurt you, unless you were trying to gouge someone's eyes out, but that would be taking the analogy too far.

Comment: Consider Molly Weasley and the Boggart during the cleaning of the Order's headquarters (Sirius Black's old London house). Clearly, a dead son can't *physically* harm you in any literal, physical sense, but a Boggart transforming into a succession of dead sons can certainly have a severe *psychological* effect on someone.

Comment: @alephzero Maybe if the dead sons were dropped on her they could harm her. :P

Comment: @Bellatrix you are cruel :D

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo Of course! ;)